# Multithreaded Transaction Parity in Spring Using Spring JPA and Transactions

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

(Using Springboot 3.1.2)
I have a service (Foo) that will call 1-3 other services (Bar, Bizz, Buzz) asynchronously. Bar Bizz and Buzz will all commit similar data across 1-3 schemas in a database. I want it so that if a transaction fails in one for any reason, we can rollback the other schemas, and if it succeeds in all 3 we save it in all 3.

I have tried putting an @Transaction around the main service Foo, however that doesn't work with mulithreadding. I have made Bar, Bizz, and Buzz all @Transactional but once their main logic ends it will commit the Transaction before the threads are joined in Foo. Is there an easy way in Spring to have parity between different transactions? Or will I have to use a more basic approach with JDBC to handle commits?

Comment: Transactions across HTTP is what you want and what doesn't exists. You need to write logic to do a compensating transaction (i.e. remove the committed stuff).

Comment: You meant SpringBoot 3.1.2? Most of Spring Source libs are at 6 now.

Comment: What you want might fall into what is called a distributed transaction, where the XA transaction manager handles the multiple transactions for you. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html as a start, and there are demos on the various options. The threads though probably should not be asynchronous - They must be able to all participate in the same transactional scope, and the transaction manager handle splitting it out into multiple XA resources. Though if all schemas on in the same DB, can they not just use the same connection/transaction?